# Network issues after setup a read only file system

Tags: filesystems, ip, ipv6, readonly, ipv4

I'm new to Linux (Raspbian Buster / Raspberry Pi 4 model B) and I have some network issues after setup a read only file system. I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/swlh/make-your-raspberry-pi-file-system-read-only-raspbian-buster-c558694de79) to realize the ro fs.

My raspberry is connected to my router via ethernet and always got an IPv4 and IPv6 address in the past.

After setup the ro fs and the following reboot the router couldn't find the raspberry anymore. Both ethernet LED's at the raspberry were continuously ON. I restarted the router but nothing changed.

After that I repowered the raspberry and now I just got an IPv4 address.

Are there some `.log` files which can't be stored in a ro fs and so the IP support can't be established?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say YES there are some files which have to be linked to a temporary RAM location.

Adding this line at the end of `/etc/fstab` did the trick.

```
tmpfs   /var/lib/dhcp   tmpfs   nosuid,nodev   0   0
```